# Null exception starting activity with intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm receiving an exception that equals `null` when attempting to create a new activity using `Intent`. Basically my program terminates when I try to create this new `Activity` i.e. switch the screen the user sees to one with an animated treasure box (png files from xml, which works when they are run from the MainActivity).

Here is a picture from Android Studio of the error I am receiving:

[image]

I'm developing a Vuzix M100 application on a device running vr4.0.4.

Here are the two activities I am running:

`MainActivity.java`

```
package com.rit.se.treasurehuntvuz;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        try {
            Intent showTreasureIntent = new Intent(this, ShowTreasureActivity.class);
            startActivity(showTreasureIntent);
        }
        catch(Exception exception) {
            Log.e("MainActivity", exception.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

`ShowTreasureActivity.java`

```
package com.rit.se.treasurehuntvuz;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ShowTreasureActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView treasureImage;
    private AnimationDrawable treasureAnimation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_showtreasure);

        treasureImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.treasureAnimationView);
        treasureImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.anim_treasure);

        treasureAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) treasureImage.getBackground();
        treasureAnimation.setOneShot(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus)
    {
        treasureAnimation.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    }
}
```

Comment: The fact that the exception is showing as null seems more like a debugger issue than a code issue. The code looks fine. Does the log statement in the catch block display anything in Logcat? Does nothing happen when you hit the back button? Did you add ShowTreasureActivity to your Manifest?

Comment: The program crashes when I hit the back button. And nothing from the logs. And yeah it was the manifest file!

Comment: are you Coming From Same activity which you Are Pass On Back Press?

Comment: going from MainActivity to ShowTreasureActivity when you Press the back button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Joel Duggan, it turned out I was lacking an entry in the manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.rit.se.treasurehuntvuz">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity android:name=".ShowTreasureActivity">
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```